# What is the Clad Genius database structure in cafw.fdb?

Tags: firebird, craigslist

Clad Genius internally uses a Firebird SQL database (cafw.fdb). I can connect to it using the Linux Firebird client, but what are these tables:

```
SQL> show tables;
       BP_ADCAT                               BP_ADREG         
       BP_CAT                                 BP_CATV          
       BP_EMA                                 BP_POST          
       BP_REG                                 CA_AD            
       CA_ADIMG                               CA_CAMPAIGN      
       CA_PROXY                               CA_REG           
       CA_TPREG                               CL_ACT           
       CL_ADCAT                               CL_ADREG         
       CL_CAT                                 CL_EMA           
       CL_POST                                CL_REG           
       GR_APP                                 GR_CC            
       GR_CHLOG                               GR_FB            
       GR_HINT                                GR_HTDE          
       GR_HTDS                                GR_IP            
       GR_IPUSAGE                             GR_MAILACT       
       GR_MAILMSG                             GR_MAILSRV       
       GR_MUSYN                               GR_MUTOK         
       GR_NAME                                GR_RAS           
       GR_TOK                                 GR_TOKVAR        
       GR_USER                                GR_USERAGENT     
       GR_VER                                 GR_ZIP           
       KI_ADCAT                               KI_ADREG         
       KI_CAT                                 KI_CATV          
       KI_EMA                                 KI_POST          
       KI_REG                                 KI_VID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few characters seem to be namespaces,

```
BP is Back Page
CL is Craigslist
KI is Kijiji (A Canadian classified)
```

I'm not yet sure what CA or GR are.